# Forward TCP connection which first byte is '{' to port 3333, otherwise to port 80, possible with iptables?

Tags: tcp, port, iptables, forward

Port 80 accept two different protocols: HTTP and Stratum. The latter is a line-based protocol always start with '{'. If the client connect to port 80 and sends something like 'GET / HTTP/1.0...', forward the connection to port 8000, if it sends '{"id": 1,...', forward it to port 3333. Is it possible to do it with iptables? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with iptables.

The problem is that, at the time you can detect the first byte of the TCP payload, a connection has been established between `source:port` to `server:80`.

Forwarding the packets in mid-connection will result in the packets being rejected, because the TCP stack never sees the SYN/SYN-ACK packets for connection establishment to ports :8000 or :3333.

You'll need *something* listening on port :80, then based on the very first by received, open a connection to port :8000 or :3333 and replay the contents. That *something* must also perform reverse-replay of the webserver's/Stratumserver's replay toward the connection initiator.